# Implement 'toggle class' functionality on a list of elements with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling with implementing 'toggle class' functionality in React.
I have the `NavSidebar` component which is an unordered list `ul`. My `NavListItem` component is list item `li`.

When the list item is clicked I need to give the class name `active` to the clicked `li` and other list elements should get an empty class name.

Here's what I've come up with by far:

```
class NavListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { active: false };
  }

  setActive(bool) {
    this.setState({ active: bool });
  }

  render() {
    let index = this.props.key;
    let item = this.props.item;
    return (
      <li className={this.state.active ? 'active' : ''}
          onClick={this.setActive(this.props.setActive).bind(this)} >
        <a href={'#'+item}>{item}</a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class NavSidebar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {

    let items = this.props.navItems.map( (item, index) => {
      return (
        <NavListItem key={index} item={item} setActive={true} />
      );
    });

    return (
        <div className="col-sm-2">
          <nav className="nav-sidebar">
            <ul className="nav">
              {items}
              <li className="nav-divider" />
              <li>
                <a href="#"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Back Home</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

NavSidebar.propTypes = {
  navItems: React.PropTypes.array
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, it never even touches the className of the elements and I can't come up with the working solution.

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no error message here?

```
onClick={this.setActive(this.props.setActive).bind(this)}
```

Because you are binding `undefined`, result of calling `this.setActive(this.props.setActive)`

and even if you remove the bind, it will not work as the click handler will be `undefined`. Also, the state should never be modified inside `render`.

In any case, because you want to update more than one item (the new selected one and the old one), the parent should be responsible of this and should:

- activate the clicked item
- deactivate all others
- re-render the list

Something like this (not tested):

```
class NavListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  setActive(bool) {
    this.props.onItemActive(this.props.item);
  }

  render() {
    let item = this.props.item;
    return (
      <li className={this.props.active ? 'active' : ''}
          onClick={this.setActive.bind(this)} >
        <a href={'#'+item}>{item}</a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class NavSidebar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {activeItem: null};
  }

  onItemActive(item) {
    this.setState({activeItem: item};
  }

  render () {
    let self = this;
    let items = this.props.navItems.map( (item, index) => {
      return (
        <NavListItem key={index} item={item} 
                     onItemActive={self.onItemActive.bind(self)} 
                     active={item === self.state.activeItem} />
      );
    });

    return (
        <div className="col-sm-2">
          <nav className="nav-sidebar">
            <ul className="nav">
              {items}
              <li className="nav-divider" />
              <li>
                <a href="#"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Back Home</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

NavSidebar.propTypes = {
  navItems: React.PropTypes.array
};
```

Comment: Could you explain what is `this.props.onActivate(this.props.item);`? And it throws `cannot read 'props' of undefined` at this line.

Comment: `this.props.onActivate` is the callback belonging to the parent passed down to children. `this.props.onActivate(this.props.item)` will call it with the clicked item as the argument.

Comment: Sorry, it's `this.props.onItemActive`. Fixed.

Comment: `cannot read property 'props' of undefined` for the line `this.props.onItemActive(this.props.item);`. And, by the waym it doesn't change the elements' classes.

Comment: That's because I forgot that with ES6 classes, React no more autobind this to non react functions. Fixed. Added `.bind(this)` to `onClick={this.setActive.bind(this)}` and `onItemActive={this.onItemActive.bind(this)}`

Comment: but it still doesn't change the names of the classes :(

Comment: Now I think it's fixed. Parent was not updating (state, props were not changed) and there was an undefined error in the map function where `this` is not what was expected. Working [**`jsfiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/oa2evaa0/) (not ES6 classes)